# Build and release on different Team-projects

Tags: tfs, build, release

I am using TFS 2017 on-premise.
I have a team project (call it "proj1") which contains the code and the build.
I have another Team project(call it "releases") which contains no code but it contains all the releases of all the different team projects (proj1,proj2...). each release process is connected to an artifact from a build (e.g. proj1)
Everything works as expected except the "Commits" Tab which says "build definition XXX was not found". XXX is of course the definition number of the build in the origin team project (proj1).

Is it a bug a feature or any idea how to bypass this?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? Keep everything related in the same team project.

Comment: I have more then a 200 team projects each have it's own continues build process. however I have something like 5 release procedures that fit most of these projects.
By using the same team project for all releases I can maintain all the releases by using the "task groups".

Answer (score 0):

That is because the build definition is not in the current team project.

Build and release on different Team-projects is not the Normal/Recommanded behavior.

So, just as Daniel said "Keep everything related **in the same team project**"

However, if you insist on that, then you can try retrieve the build definition information by calling the REST API ([Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1))